# Using just the right number of logical processors

Tags: c++, windows, intel, tbb

Is there a way that I can (using tbb from intel) specify the number of logical processors used by their parallel loops? Like i.e. I'd like to be able to detect number of logical processors and specify how many of them I'd like to use for this task.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That's TBBs job.

Comment: @ronag I'd like to be able to specify it myself in certain circumstances (if possible)

Comment: In what "certain circumstance"? I can't think of a single circumstance where you'd want to do that.

Comment: @ronag let's say that I have 4 processors. I want for my tasks use just 2 of them (in order to use the other two for different purposes)

Comment: Maybe search for "CPU pinning". Not sure if that's the right thing, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB +1 This is actually called CPU affinity but I think is the step in the right direction.

Comment: @smallB: Ah, yes, that sounds familiar. Good luck, and do post if you find a solution!

Comment: @KerrekSB sure will (if I manage to do it)

Comment: "I want for my tasks use just 2 of them (in order to use the other two for different purposes)". Why would you want to do that? You are wasting load-balancing possibilities...

Comment: Also I don't think you really mean processors, but physical threads.

Comment: @ronag I mean processors, and I (to answer to your previous post) would want to do that in situation when I have other, more important work to do which would use rest of processors, and this less important work would use max two.

Comment: @smallB: Then you should use task-priorities (which TBB supports) or set thread priorities and let the OS schedule your threads correspondingly. The way you would want to do it will be a lot slower than just setting thread priotities for those threads that do "important" work. Since some of the "processors" might run out of work, while the others have to much work, you basically disable any form of load balancing...

Comment: @ronag the wanted minimal number of processors is accessed from different application to the application doing the "important" job

Comment: @smallB: I still don't think you mean processors, you mean physical threads. A desktop computer has one processor which might have several cores which might have 1 or 2 physical threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean threads, and not processors.

```
int main()
{
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(num_threads);
    ...
}
```

Though I still think it's better to just let TBB handle it automatically.

EDIT: based on comments, what you want is this:

```
int main()
{
    struct tbb_set_affinity : public tbb::task_scheduler_observer
    {
         tbb_set_affinity(){observe(true);}
         void on_scheduler_entry(bool is_worker)
         {
            SetThreadAffinityMask(...);
         }
   } tbb_set_affinity;

   tbb::task_scheduler_init init(num_processors);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I do agree with you that in most cases it is better to let tbb to handle it automatically. But there are certain circumstances when you want let the user to decide/be able to decide.

Comment: I do not know if ronag's answer is correct but it makes sense. If you want to limit the number of processors used by your function, then you have to limit the number of threads started/activated by your function...

Comment: @Malkocoglu no, your logic is broken.

Comment: @smallB: actually your logic is broken, if you only have 2 threads then it will only use max 2 processors, I'm guessing what you want is some thread affinity.

Comment: @ronag: Thread affinity is discouraged on most OSes because it really messes up scheduling and often decreases performance.  I'd avoid it if possible.

Comment: @AndréCaron he (Malkocoglu) says (incorrectly) that: "If you want to limit the number of processors used by your function, then you have to limit the number of threads started/activated by your function", and I'm saying that I don't have to limit the number of threads if I'm limiting number of processors. If I use two threads on two processors, even if I use just one processor I CAN STILL use those two threads. That's why his logic is broken.

Comment: smallB: Sorry, but that doesn't make much sense to me. There is no way to "limit" the number of "processors", the only way to do it is by limiting the number of threads and possibly setting affinity.

Comment: @ronag what doesn't make sense to you? That I don't have to decrease number of threads if I have less processors available?

Comment: There is no such thing as "limiting" the number of processors which is why your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ronag if there is no way to limit number of processors, then that should be the first and only answer to my question:"No there is no way to specify the number of processors used by their parallel loops". And that would close the discussion.

Comment: @ronag my comment makes sense. If you can limit number of processors but not threads then it does make perfect sense. If you cannot possibly (no tools available) limit no of proc, then it still makes sense, theoretically speaking, but practically impossible. BUT IT MAKES SENSE.

Comment: @ronag but thanks for your answer, will accept. I think that the task_scheduler will do what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @ronag by using sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors I'm getting result 8

Comment: @smallB: dwNumberOfProcessors is the number of *logical* processors, or more commonly called the number of **hardware/physical threads**.

Comment: @ronag ok, thanks I didn't know that. Is there a way to detect physical number of processors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8484/discussion-between-smallb-and-ronag)